# How to use DMA memory to memory in stm32h723zgt6?

Tags: memory, dma, stm32h7

How to use DMA memory to memory in stm32H723zgt6, the following code doesn't work properly, how can I modify it?

My version of the HAL library is v1.9.0:

```
int dma1_sm1_test(dmaSMStruct *dmaSM)
{
    DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_memtomem_dma1_stream7;
    
    uint8_t srcData[10] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x80};
    uint8_t dstData[10];
    uint16_t srcCrc = 0xA9B0;
    uint16_t crcRes = 0;
    
    /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* Configure DMA request hdma_memtomem_dma1_stream7 on DMA1_Stream7 */
  hdma_memtomem_dma1_stream7.Instance = DMA1_Stream7;
  hdma_memtomem_dma1_stream7.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_MEM2MEM;
  hdma_memtomem_dma1_stream7.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_MEMORY;
  hdma_memtomem_dma1_stream7.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_ENABLE;
  hdma_memtomem_dma1_stream7.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
  hdma_memtomem_dma1_stream7.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
  hdma_memtomem_dma1_stream7.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
  hdma_memtomem_dma1_stream7.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
  hdma_memtomem_dma1_stream7.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
  hdma_memtomem_dma1_stream7.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_ENABLE;
  hdma_memtomem_dma1_stream7.Init.FIFOThreshold = DMA_FIFO_THRESHOLD_FULL;
  hdma_memtomem_dma1_stream7.Init.MemBurst = DMA_MBURST_SINGLE;
  hdma_memtomem_dma1_stream7.Init.PeriphBurst = DMA_PBURST_SINGLE;
    hdma_memtomem_dma1_stream7.XferCpltCallback = &DmaXfercompleteCallback;
  if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_memtomem_dma1_stream7) != HAL_OK)
  {
    ;
  }
    
    HAL_DMA_Start(&hdma_memtomem_dma1_stream7, (uint32_t)srcData, (uint32_t)dstData, 10);
    
    while(!(__HAL_DMA_GET_FLAG(&hdma_memtomem_dma1_stream7, DMA_FLAG_TCIF3_7)))
    {
        ;
    }
    crcRes = crc16(dstData, 8);
    
    if(crcRes == srcCrc)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I've debugged it with keil simulation, and I see that the DMA registers are configured, but it still doesn't transfer data.